# Show that if the curve $y = f(x)$ has a maximum stationary point at $x = a$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am looking for help in solving the following problem:

> Show that if the curve $y = f(x)$ has a maximum stationary point at $x = a$ then the curve $y = \frac {1}{f(x)}$ has a minimum stationary point at $x = a$ as long as $f(a) \neq 0$.

Thank you.

Edit: Thank you for all the comments. However, I made a mistake in my post, which changes the exercise, and the answer, obviously. I wrongly typed =, where it should be $\neq$. I would be glad if somebody helped me - I still do not know how to start.

Comment: What progress have you made so far? Do you know what you would need to show in order to show that a function has a minimum stationary point at $x=a$?

Comment: Did you mean $f (a) \neq 0$?

Comment: Oh yes, my fault. I meant exactly what you, Rodrigo de Azevedo, pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

You could think about a specific example such as;
$$f(x)=\sin(x)$$
and its maximum at 
$$\big(\frac{\pi}{2},1\big)$$
and then about
$$\frac{1}{f(x)}=\csc(x)=\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$$
and it's minimum at
$$\big(\frac{\pi}{2},1\big)$$
to get a feel for the question before trying to generalise.

Or some other specific example.

(I've been trying to think of another, easier, example)

How about,
$$f(x)=1-x^2$$
with a maximum at (0,1)
and
$$\frac{1}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$$
with a minimum at (0,1) ?

Comment: I have changed some details about the exercise. Would you mind solving it again? Thank you.

Comment: It doesn’t change my answer as I avoided the division by zero situation anyway.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\left[\frac{1}{f(x)}\right]'=-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}$$ and $$\left[\frac{1}{f(x)}\right]''=-\left[\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}\right]'=-\frac{f''(x)f(x)^2-2f(x)f'(x)^2}{f(x)^4}.$$ Then, at the point in question, being $x=a,$ by hypothesis we have $f(x)\neq 0, f'(x)=0,f''(x)<0.$

Can you complete it now?

---

As @TonyK has pointed out, this approach does not work, so I guess we'll have to go back to definitions.

If $f(x)$ has a maximum value at $x=a,$ then for all sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$ we must have $$\begin {align} {f'(a-\epsilon)>0 \\f'(a+\epsilon)<0}\end {align}.$$ A similar definition holds for minimum points, only now with the inequality symbols reversed. We now do not need second derivatives. Using first derivatives and the above definitions gives your result (together with the other assumptions, of course).

Comment: I have changed some details about the exercise. Would you mind solving it again? Thank you.

Comment: @Marcin I knew you did make a mistype and assumed the correct thing. See my last line, where I assumed $f(x)\neq 0$ for $x=a.$ I need change nothing. Indeed, if I had not made that assumption from the beginning my answer would have been completely wrong.

Comment: We don't know that $f''(x)<0$. For instance, $f(x)=-x^4$ has a maximum at $x=0$, but $f''(0)=0$. This destroys your answer, I think.

Comment: @TonyK True, that. I have now made an edition.

Answer (score 0):

As Allawonder shows with

$$\left[\frac{1}{f(x)}\right]'=-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}$$

$1/f$ has a stationary point at $a$. But to show that this point is a minimum, we need to go back to first principles:

$f(a)$ is a maximum, so there exists $\delta>0$ such that when $|x-a|<\delta$, then (i) $f(x)\le f(a)$ and (ii) $f(x)$ and $f(a)$ have the same sign.

But if $f(x)\le f(a)$, and $f(x)$ and $f(a)$ have the same sign, then $1/f(x)\ge 1/f(a)$. So $1/f(x)$ has a minimum at $a$.

Comment: Oh, you also added an answer. But why make the additional assumption that $f(x)>0$ near $x=a$? I see no such assumption in the OP. I know you did it because of the inversion, of course, but it is not justified.

Comment: @Allawonder: It is required, because (as you say) of the inversion. As for justification: if $f$ has a stationary point at $a$, then it must be differentiable there, and hence 
continuous.

Comment: You seem not to understand me. You have proved the theorem only for when the maximum is positive. For example, you have not proved the theorem in the case of your example $-x^4.$

Comment: @Allawonder: Oh I see. Yes, you are correct. I will try to put it right!